# New to TDD: Are there sample applications with tests to show how to do TDD?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

I really want to get into TDD development but I have no point of reference where to start.

I think that looking at code and seeing how they write tests and make classes testable that it'll be easier for me to digest and start using myself.

Is anyone aware of any sample or small open source **`C#`** applications that include unit tests?

Comment: To add further, I would like to see a series on how to develop a project with unit-testing, mocking, CI & all related stuff. However small, a real life example will help.

Comment: Would be good for me also. I would love to see a series where someone first defines what they are going to build, does their design then starts writing it all test first. However I've found nothing. The closest is kent becks book but even then he works on a piece of functionality not a whole project, and you miss a lot of the "where do I start from here"

Answer (score 6):

For shakalpesh,

I would recommend the ObjectMentor katas.

- One is to create a bowling game scoring algorithm
- Another is to convert infix expressions to postfix. (The shunting yard algorithm)

[Bolwing Game](http://butunclebob.com/files/downloads/Bowling%20Game%20Kata.ppt)

[Shunting Yard Algorithm](http://blog.objectmentor.com/articles/2009/06/24/shunting-yard-algorithm-kata)

Answer (score 3):

I *highly* recommend "[Test Driven Development: By Example (Addison-Wesley Signature Series)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321146530)" by Kent Beck.

Far, far better than any other resources I've found on the net or elsewhere.  Well worth the $40 - $50.

Comment: It's very short for the price. Most of the info can be had from programming blogs.

Comment: The book is indeed very nice. The two step by step examples are good introductions to the TDD process and the patterns presented in the last chapter are useful too. Besides, I certainly enjoyed K. Beck's writing style - it looks as if he's right besides you doing the stuff. A great introduction to TDD for a novice, highly recommended. The only thing I thought was missing was a deeper discussion on mocks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a real-life open source application where the unit tests are critical to evaluating correctness, I'd suggest [BouncyCastle C#](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/), the source is available [here](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/download/bccrypto-net-1.4-src.zip). It's an open source crypto API for .NET, has loads of tests and obviously the tests
help establish whether things are working or not. Great if you like jumping into the thick of things.

Answer (score 0):

I personally believe it's better to see web / screencasts for this than reading sample source code.

I'd go watch Rob Connery's MVC storefront series [here](http://blog.wekeroad.com/mvc-storefront/).  He covers most of what you are looking for.

Also, look at DnRTV episodes w/ JP Boodhoo.  Find it [here](http://www.dnrtv.com/archives.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Press has the book, ["Test Driven Development in Microsoft .NET"](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/books/6778.aspx), by Newkirk and Vorontsov, two members of the NUnit development team.  It's a few years old now, but it'll show you a more complete view of the process.